# jupyter nbconvert --to slides generates blank page

Tags: python, python-2.7, jupyter, reveal.js, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to export my IPython/Jupyter Notebook to HTML slides using the Reveal.js library, but the result is a blank page.

I have seen the raised issues about it, but none solved my problem (using local Reveal librayr, using Reveal.js v2 ou v3).

I am using Jupyter version 4.0.6 and Python 2.7.

Please find below the command and the server log.

### jupyter nbconvert --to slides  --ServePostProcessor.port=8910 --post serve pricing.ipynb

[NbConvertApp] Converting notebook pricing.ipynb to slides

[NbConvertApp] Writing 1725694 bytes to pricing.slides.html

[NbConvertApp] Serving local reveal.js

Serving your slides at http://127.0.0.1:8910/pricing.slides.html

Use Control-C to stop this server

WARNING:tornado.access:404 GET /custom.css (127.0.0.1) 3.00ms

Answer (score 1):

Try deleting reveal.js from your local path and run the following command.

```
jupyter nbconvert Slide.ipynb --to slides --post serve
```

looks for the js on the web:
.
.
.
Redirecting reveal.js requests to https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/reveal.js/3.1.0

I also found something which might help.

http://www.damian.oquanta.info/posts/using-a-local-revealjs-library-with-your-ipython-slides.html

Comment: It generates a plain html. It respects my selection of cells to skip, though.
But the plotly charts are also not rendered.